# does facebook embedded video api still support removeListener()?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

According to facebook documentation - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player/api , we subscribe to player events

```
    var handleDesktopEvents = function (msg) {
        if (msg.type === 'video') {
            var player = msg.instance;
            var playHandler = player.subscribe('startedPlaying', function() {
                // Video started playing ...
                player.unmute();
                console.log('detected video playing');
                ga_virtual_pagehit(msg.id);
                console.log('sent event to GA');
                playHandler.removeListener('startedPlaying');
                // playHandler.release();
            });
            console.log('detected video ready');
            player.play();
            FB.Event.unsubscribe('xfbml.ready', handleDesktopEvents, handleDesktopEx);
        }
    };
    var  handleDesktopEx = function () {
        // Handle pause() and exceptions
        console.log('detected pause');
    };

    FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.ready',  handleDesktopEvents, handleDesktopEx);
```

It seems that `removeListener()` is not available on the token returned by `subscribe()`. With a debugger, we see that there is a method `release()` available on the token. Should that be used? Is it now official?

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Also having this problem and looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there was and probably still is, unless FB changed something again, a release() method. it does what removeListen() should be doing.