# How to config the video embedded by the Facebook embed-video-player-plugin

Tags: javascript, facebook, video, sdk

I've embedded a video by use [Facebook video plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player). If a user opens the page in a phone by vertical mode, the video width would keep as wide as the screen width when the user changes it to horizontal screen mode, so there is an empty area beside the video.

In order to solute this, I want to make it playing in fullscreen when the user clicks the Play Button. I have checked the docs but not find a solution for configuring dynamically the video's width and fullscreen status.

I checked links below but no result:

- [Facebook embeded video with iframe not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26479957/facebook-embeded-video-with-iframe-not-working)
- [Responsive facebook embed video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42263810/responsive-facebook-embed-video)
- [does facebook embedded video api still support removeListener()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38745635/does-facebook-embedded-video-api-still-support-removelistener?rq=1)

Comment: There is no way for you to trigger fullscreen automatically, the user has to do that. // Facebook explicitly says that most of their social plugins are only “responsive” in that they will adapt somewhat to the conditions on page load/when the plugin was rendered; but the don’t _dynamically_ adapt to changes after that.

Comment: @CBroe Yeah. So I want to solute in another way (haven't found)

Comment: Well then the most you can do, is replace the rendered plugin with a “new” one when the orientation of the device changes. You could subscribe to the available events to figure out whether the video was still paused or is already playing, and if it was playing “seek” to the same position again, before you call the play method of the “replacement” … but that’s gonna be a bit complex to implement, likely not going to perform very well, and whether users will like the interruption to an already playing video this will cause is doubtful.

Comment: @CBroe It seems to take time to reload the video if replace plugin with a "new", so that's would be a bad experience for the user watching a video.

Comment: Well as I said, that’s likely not going to work very smoothly … You could perhaps try and get _two_ versions of the plugin rendered in different sizes, and then only toggle between those two, instead of creating “new” ones. But the issue that you will have to deal with pausing the one and getting the other to “continue” playing from that position then, will remain. Not worth the hassle IMHO.

Comment: @CBroe Oh. That's really a new perspective.